# How can I use a COUNTIF or VLOOKUP to get the number to the right of text on a different worksheet?

Tags: excel

Essentially to save myself some time I have been constructing a dashboard in multiple excel files. Each have their own dashboard which has information from various other worksheets in the workbook.

The problem at hand now is this. I have a page full of "Returns" I had been previously using a statement such as this:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D20,'Work-Findings'!$F$5:$G$44,2,FALSE),0)
```

This was in a cell on the dashboard it would look at the EXACT text the left of the cell and search in the 'Work-Findings' page and send back the number to the right of the page with that EXACT wording.

I have a situation where I need it to look for the wording that **STARTS** with a certain word. Or starting with the words "Externally Induced"

The reason I need it to start and the above code won't fully work unless I do it for all situations is because I have multiple situations that can happen

Externally Induced: Reason 1
Externally Induced: Reason 2
Externally Induced: Reason 3
Externally Induced: Reason 4
Externally Induced: Reason 5

I could just do it on the dashboard for all those specific text possibilities but there has to be an easier way to just specify count if anything starts with Externally Induced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wildcards in VLOOKUP:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D20 & "*",'Work-Findings'!$F$5:$G$44,2,FALSE),0)
```

This will now find the first one that has it in the beginning.

If you want to return the value directly to the right of every one that starts with the search criteria then a SUMPRODUCT would work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D20,'Work-Findings'!$F$5:$F$44)))*'Work-Findings'!$G$5:$G$44)
```

IF all you want is a count of those that match then:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D20,'Work-Findings'!$F$5:$F$44)))*1)
```

Comment: Thank you it appears as though the SUMPRODUCT is exactly what I'm looking for !